# Problemas ao instalar um serviço no Windows Server

Tags: c#

1. Desenvolvi um aplicativo no Windows Service, no Visual Studio;
   [image: Projeto em Visual Studio]
2. Não consigo instalar o serviço no Windows Server;
3. fiz uma mudança sugerida e também não esta registrando, ocorrendo o seguinte problema:
   [image: Erro ai Executar o comando installutil.exe]
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Iniciei o prompt como administrador e não funcionou.
5. Me loguei como administrador e não funcionou.

Comment: Dê uma lida nisso aqui: [ask]

Comment: _eu pesquisei e muito.. todas as respostas que encontrei não funcionaram e alguns peguem para utilizar install shield e para o Visual Studio 14 não funciona o install shield. Agora eu nao sou um grande conhecedor de visual studio venho perguntar aqui..._

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta colocando o conteúdo do `InstallLog`, por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce esta rodando o Prompt como administrador?
Se for windows 8 sugiro que tente efetuar a mesma operação em um window 7.

Porem eu ja tive alguns problemas com o installutil.exe... por isso faço o seguinte:

Adicione a referencia `System.Configuration.Install` no seu serviço no visual studio.
No Main.cs ou Program.cs (depende da sua aplicação) coloque o seguinte codigo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        string parameter = string.Concat(args);
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "--install":
            ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
            break;
            case "--uninstall":
            ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //aqui é seu codigo para rodar o serviço normalmente.
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                          { 
                              new ValidatorService() 
                          };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Agora voce apenas chama no cmd o programa gerado: Servico.exe com o argumento --install para instalar o serviço...para desistalar utilize o --uninstall.
E agora pode jogar fora o installutil.exe

Comment: _Eu tentei   fiz ate outros aplicativos..   sera problema com o windows server 2012_

Comment: Se voce efetuou o processo e deu o mesmo erro quer dizer que esta faltando alguma dependencia... Vi que voce esta executando via G:/ ... tente copiar todas as dlls para uma pasta local junto com o iservicos.exe e execute novamente o processo de instalação.

Comment: _Obrigado funcionou das duas maneiras.. voce estava copiei tudo para a mesma pasta e foi resolvido, muito obrigado pela atenção e ajuda_

Answer (score 2):

Por dedução, aparentemente a unidade `G:\` corresponde a um **mapeamento de rede**.
Neste caso, a instalação de fato irá falhar.

Tente mover todas as dependências para uma unidade local (`C:`) e instale o serviço naquele diretório.

Se `G:\` for um mapeamento a uma unidade da própria máquina local, utilize o caminho original ao qual o mapeamento aponta para registrar o executável do serviço. Exemplo:

`installutil.exe c:\meu_mapeamento\iERP\(...)\iServicos.exe`

Comment: _Sua resposta ajudou obrigado, tanto a sua resposta como a do nosso outro colega resolveu como solução_